# How to compare GET request result with .xml file by the mockMvc

Tags: java, xml

I have controller methods test, for example:

```
@Test
public void getCustomers() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/customers/listdata")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

and i have .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customers>
<customer>
    <id>1</id>
    <firstName>Nick</firstName>
    <lastName>First</lastName>
</customer>
<customer>
    <id>2</id>
    <firstName>Paul</firstName>
    <lastName>Second</lastName>
</customer>
<customer>
    <id>3</id>
    <firstName>Josh</firstName>
    <lastName>Third</lastName>
</customer>
```

so how can i compare GET result with my .xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Do you need to compare it against the whole file? If so, you would just convert it to a string and compare that (possibly using [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/) for canonicalization & etc). e.g.:

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(...).andReturn();
String body = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
assertThat(body, is("<customers>...</customers>");
```

Alternatively, if all you need is to check individual xPath expressions, you can do that like so:

```
mvc
.perform(...)
.andExpect(
    MockMvcResultMatchers
        .xpath("/customers/customer[1]/id").string(is("1"))
);
```

Comment: I need to compare query(for example http://localhost:8080/customers/listdata) result (in xml format) with concrete listdata.xml file without converting it into string. How can i specify that file in my test?